# Hiding/Showing Contents inside a <div> using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

I was wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Basically I want to show and hide text within a div when I hover over an image(depending on which image).

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.project_desc_1','.project_desc_2').hide();

    $('#project1').hover(function() {
        $('.project_desc_1').show();
    }, function() {
        $('.project_desc_2').hide();
    });

    $('#project2').hover(function() {
        $('.project_desc_2').show();
    }, function() {
        $('.project_desc_1').hide();
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="current_projects">
    <h1>Current Projects</h1>

    <div class="projects_gallery" align="center">

        <img src="./images/blivori.png"/ id="project1">
        <img src="./images/blivori.png"/ id="project2">

        <div class="project_desc_1">
            Project Description 1
        </div>

        <div class="project_desc_2">
            Project Description 2
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `$('.project_desc_1','.project_desc_2')` should be `$('.project_desc_1, .project_desc_2')` But do you want something like that instead: http://jsfiddle.net/9V2dT/

Comment: @A.Wolff Nope, not working sorry. div content is visible from page load and nothing happens on mouseover.

Comment: It would work if you change HTML markup according to it, just as in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you are trying to show description based on image like Hover `project1` show `project_desc_1` and Hover `project2` show `project_desc_2`.

You have few things missing here:

1. change `$('.project_desc_1', '.project_desc_2').hide();` to `$('.project_desc_1, .project_desc_2').hide();`
2. Change this html code

from:

```
<img src="./images/blivori.png/" id="project1">
<img src="./images/blivori.png/" id="project2">
```

to

```
<img src="./images/blivori.png" id="project1">
<img src="./images/blivori.png" id="project2">
```

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.project_desc_1, .project_desc_2').hide();

     $('#project1').hover(function() {
       $('.project_desc_1').show();
         $('.project_desc_2').hide();
      });

    $('#project2').hover(function() {
     $('.project_desc_2').show();
    $('.project_desc_1').hide();
            });
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7t6AH/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're missing a pair of closing braces after the second hover function.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.project_desc_1, .project_desc_2').hide();

    $('#project1').hover(function() {
        // when the mouse ENTERS the image
        $('.project_desc_1').show();
        $('.project_desc_2').hide();
    }, function() {
        // when the mouse LEAVES the image
        $('.project_desc_1').hide();
    });

    $('#project2').hover(function() {
        // when the mouse ENTERS the image
        $('.project_desc_1').hide();
        $('.project_desc_2').show();
    }, function() {
        // when the mouse LEAVES the image
        $('.project_desc_2').hide();
    });
}
```

The code should hide the div that is irrelevant on enter and hide the relevant div on leave. Try this out and see if it works!

In case you would like to see this working - check out the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kZPQp/

Comment: Hi.. unfortunately it didn't work. Both divs are visible from page load and nothing happens when i hover with the mouse.

Comment: Added a JSFiddle so you can see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/kZPQp/. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably simplify things and get rid of the project1/project2 business.  This is not friendly to the way you do things in jQuery.

I would suggest this HTML:

```
<div class="current_projects">
    <h1>Current Projects</h1>
    <div class="projects_gallery" align="center">
        <img src="./images/blivori.png"/ class="project_trigger">
        <img src="./images/blivori.png"/ class="project_trigger">
        <div class="project_desc">
            Project Description 1
        </div>
        <div class="project_desc">
            Project Description 2
        </div>
    </div>
```

With the following jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.project_desc').hide();  // Personally I would hide in CSS such that this step is not needed and possible flashing of content before onload wouldn't happen

    $('.project_trigger').hover(
        function() {
            var i = $('.project_trigger').index(this);
            // hide all descriptions
            // then show only description with index position
            // matching index position of trigger
            $('project_desc').hide()
                .eq(i)
                .show();
        },
        function() {
            // hide all descriptions
            $('project_desc').hide();
        }
    );
});
```

This is much more scalable and allows any number of trigger items and target items without you having to change your javascript. Of course the number of triggers and descriptions should be equal and the order of these would be important.